# Pandas: Nondeterministic broadcast failure in variable assignment

Tags: python, pandas

This is a cut down version of a program that converts trade data into OHLCV format.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({ 'time' : [pd.Timestamp('2017-12-26 16:01:04.628431600')], 'price': [100.0], 'size': [0.06] })
data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
data = data.resample('1s').apply({ 'price' : 'ohlc', 'size': 'sum' })
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 1404, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = values
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = data.resample('1s').apply({ 'price' : 'ohlc', 'size': 'sum' })
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 293, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 560, in _aggregate
    result = DataFrame(result)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 224, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 360, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5236, in _arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5546, in _homogenize
    raise_cast_failure=False)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2922, in _sanitize_array
    subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/jun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 1407, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 1
```

This doesn't make sense.  IIUC, the assignment on line 5 is just assigning a new `DataFrame` to a variable, so there's nothing to broadcast.  Stranger even, this failure is non-deterministic: running the script sometimes results in the error, but sometimes it doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in pandas?  Where's the source of non-determinism in this program?  I'm using Python 3.5.3 with pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: FYI.. in Pandas version (0.21.0) the code runs fine.

Comment: You're right, I should have tried that.  Thanks for the tip!